# load a php page with a cron job

Tags: php, cron, apache

I am using a cron job to reload my httpd service after a subdomain is created. I have the problem that when the reload happens the page that registers the user throws a server error.

i was wondering if i could go around this by having another cron task.

So my logic would be

httpd reload after a .conf file is created
then take the user back to the DocumentRoot of the main page.

So in usage it would be

a user registers, then is automatically taken back to `domain.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do ajax requests in the background until the server is completely restarted, when the first successful ajax request gets back, do the redirect.

Comment: .... ajax... holly molly i forgot about passing the registration data thru an ajax request. hold on let me give it a try!